# Firebase Ionic - Returning Error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have a condition where I am checking if username is taken or not. If not, then I check if email is registered or not (if not, then proceed with account creation). I am separating firebase functions from business logic...but I am unable to figure out how to return error from createUserWithEmailAndPassword() to page class to handle further.

```
if(usernameTaken) {


            }else{
                /*Username is available - Check email taken or not (if not, register)*/
                      var error = self.firebaseProvider.registerUser(self.email,self.password,self.username, self.name);

                if(error.code !== ""){
                    if(error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use"){
                        let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: 'Email Exists',
                          subTitle: 'The email you entered is already registered.',
                          buttons: ['Retry']
                        });
                        alert.present();
                      }else if(error.code == 'auth/weak-password') {
                        let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: 'Validation Error',
                          subTitle: 'The password entered is weak and should be 6 characters.',
                          buttons: ['Retry']
                        });
                        alert.present();
                      }
                }
            }
```

And here is the code in firebase.ts:

```
registerUser(email: string, password: string, username: string, name: string): (any) {
      var self = this;  

      this.fbAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        self.createUserRecord(username, email, name);    
      }).catch(function(error) {
        //Handle error
        return error;
      });

  }
```

The returned error is null (undefined) hence nothing is working as expected. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs a bit of refactoring, your parent call is expecting a promise so `var error` is going to by a `thenable` object, it's not going to have a response of `err.code`.

Also returning an `error` in your `registerUser` class as a successful response can be difficult to debug so it's best to made the catch handle on the parent call.

```
if (usernameTaken) {

} else 
  /*Username is available - Check email taken or not (if not, register)*/
  self.firebaseProvider.registerUser(self.email,self.password,self.username, self.name)
    .then(resp => {
      // Do Something
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (error.code !== "") {
        if(error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use"){
          let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Email Exists',
            subTitle: 'The email you entered is already registered.',
            buttons: ['Retry']
          });

          alert.present();
        } else if(error.code == 'auth/weak-password') {
          let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Validation Error',
            subTitle: 'The password entered is weak and should be 6 characters.',
            buttons: ['Retry']
          });

          alert.present();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

You need to add a `return` in front of the `this.fbAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` call.

```
registerUser(email: string, password: string, username: string, name: string): Promise<any> {
  var self = this;  

  return this.fbAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      return self.createUserRecord(username, email, name);    
    });
}
```

Now if the function throws an error it's handled in the parent class and you can see the difference between `createUserRecord` and an `error`.